# Show that total energy is conserved

Tags: calculus

Question is as followed

> $\textbf{F} = f(r) \textbf{r}$ where $r = |\textbf{r}|$
>
> $$U(r) = -\int rf(r)dr$$
>
> $$K=\frac{1}{2} m|\textbf{v}|^2$$
>
> Show that $E=K+U$ is constant by deriving in terms of $t$.

I tried for quite a bit and couldn't find it. I put the derivative of $\frac{dU(r)}{dt}$ into Wolframalpha and found that I was deriving $U$ incorrectly. I'm hoping someone can explain how to derive $U$ correctly. I was able to solve it after getting $\frac{dU}{dt}$.

My attempt was:

$$\frac{dU}{dt} = -r'f(r)-rf'(r)r' $$

Apologies for the poor formatting, I'm a little new to this. Thanks everyone.

Edit: Not sure if this will help but a pic of the question is here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTqsY.png

Answer (score 1):

By Newton's second law, $\mathbf{F} = m\mathbf{\ddot{r}}$. By the chain rule,

$$\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}m\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{\dot{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}) = \frac{1}{2}m(2\mathbf{\ddot{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}) = m\mathbf{\ddot{r}}\cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$

and

$$\frac{dU}{dt} = U'(r) \frac{dr}{dt} = -f(r)r\, \frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r}} = -f(r)r\, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{r}}}\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r}) = \frac{-f(r)}{2}(2\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}) = -\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{v}$$

Hence

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{dK}{dt} + \frac{dU}{dt} = \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$$

showing that $E$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $U$ is

$$ U(r) = -\int \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$$

Since $\textbf{F}$ is always in the same direction as $\textbf{r}$, we can simplify it to

$$ U(r) = - \int F\,dr$$

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

$$\frac{dU}{dr} = -\frac{d}{dr}\int F\,dr = -F = -ma $$

By the chain rule

$$ \frac{dU}{dt} = \frac{dU}{dr}\cdot \frac{dr}{dt} = -mav $$

You also have

$$\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2} mv^2 \right) = mv\,\frac{dv}{dt} = mva$$

EDIT: Following the question's definition, we have

$$\frac{dU}{dr} = -\frac{d}{dr}\int r\,f(r)\,dr = -r\,f(r) = -|\textbf{F}| = -F$$

And the rest stays the same

Comment: Hey Dylan. Can you explain how you got the first part? I can follow what you did afters but I'm not sure how you got the definition for U. I'm not sure if there was a misunderstanding but, _r_ = | **r** |, not vector **r**.

Comment: That is the general definition for $U$. The dot product is there because $\textbf{F}$ and $\textbf{r}$ are both vectors while $U$ is a scalar. Writing $\textbf{F} = f(r) \textbf{r}$ is only to show that $\textbf{F}$ is always in the direction of $\textbf{r}$, so $\textbf{F}\cdot \textbf{r} = F\,dr$ and the integral can be simplified down to just the magnitudes. Generally in one-dimensional movement you only need to use the second definition.

Comment: @AllenLee I edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not getting it entirely. I think I'll just sit on it for a bit and see if it comes to me. Thanks!!

Comment: @AllenLee What don't you get?

Comment: An answer key was actually uploaded today and it matches the answer as above. I follow that a lot more, so I'm all good now. Thanks :) !!